# save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am working with django rest framework registration and login. and i receive this error **save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'**

this is my serializers.py

```
class clientnameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = clientname
        fields = ('id','username','password', 'password2' , 'email')
        ordering = ['id',]
        extra_kwargs = {
          'password': {'write_only': True}
        }
    def save(self):
      account = clientname(
        email=self.validated_data['email'],
        username=self.validated_data['username']
      )
      password = self.validated_data['password'],
      password2 = self.validated_data['password2']
      
      if password != password2:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords must match.'})
      account.set_password(password)
      account.save()
      return account
```

as you can see i have ""account.save()"" in my serializer because it is very important when you have to override the save method,

this is my views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def registration_view(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = clientnameSerializer(data=request.data)
    data={}
    if serializer.is_valid():
      account = clientname.save()
      data['response'] = "successfully registered a new user."
      data['email'] = account.email
      data['username'] = account.username
    else:
      data = serializer.errors
    return Response(data)
```

this is the error i get when i tried to register an account

```
Exception Value: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

this is the full traceback

Traceback:

```
File "/home/schoolsite/schoolsitedir/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/schoolsite/schoolsitedir/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/schoolsite/schoolsitedir/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/schoolsite/schoolsitedir/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/schoolsite/schoolsitedir/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/schoolsite/schoolsitedir/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  505.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/home/schoolsite/schoolsitedir/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  465.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/home/schoolsite/schoolsitedir/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in raise_uncaught_exception
  476.         raise exc

File "/home/schoolsite/schoolsitedir/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  502.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/schoolsite/schoolsitedir/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py" in handler
  50.             return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/schoolsite/schoolsitedir/Homepage/api/views.py" in registration_view
  25.       account = clientname.save()
```

Comment: Which of these lines raises that error? Please post the entire traceback too.

Comment: @deceze i update my question please see

Comment: And `clientname` is a model class? Then what do you expect `clientname.save()` to do?

Comment: yes, client name is a model class, to save in my database

Comment: I put clientname.save() in order to save the data into my database @deceze, what should i do to fix my problem?

Comment: You can call `save` on an *instance* of the class, it makes no sense to call it on the class which doesn't even contain any data. You probably wanted `serializer.save()`?

Comment: @deceze i put it because i override the save method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> account = clientname.save()
> ```

This makes no sense. You probably want:

```
account = serializer.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

How about you validate if password1==password2 in your frontend application so that only the password is submitted. cause this is REST API you might just want sometime to pass data withought the two passwords.